# How to calculate WindowSizeClass in Jetpack Compose @Preview

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to preview my top level Jetpack Compose screen and check if it correctly adapts to different screen sizes. I use the width of `WindowSizeClass` to decide how to render the screen. This is the currently suggested method in the [Android dev guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive).

How can I preview if my composable is working as intended on multiple devices without hard coding the value for `WindowWidthSizeClass`?

Ideally I would want to use `calculateWindowSizeClass` which requires an `Activity` as a parameter. But this doesn't work in a Preview unless I deploy it to a device.

My current preview looks like this:

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi
@Preview(
    name = "Smartphone, Nokia X20",
    group = "Smartphone",
    showSystemUi = true,
    device = "spec:width=1080px,height=2400px,dpi=400",

    )
@Preview(
    name = "Tablet, Nokia T20",
    group = "Tablet",
    showSystemUi = true,
    device = "spec:width=1200px,height=2000px,dpi=280"
)
@Composable
fun MasterDataScreenPreview() {
    // calculateWindowSizeClass does not work in Android Studio Preview.
    val windowWidthSize = calculateWindowSizeClass(LocalContext.current.getActivity()!!).widthSizeClass
    MyAppTheme {
        Surface {
            MainScreenContent(
                uiState = MainScreenUiState(),
                windowSize = windowWidthSize,
            )
        }
    }
}

fun Context.getActivity(): ComponentActivity? = when (this) {
    is ComponentActivity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.getActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

Alternatively I could split this single preview in two separate previews and pass `WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact` for the smartphone and `WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium` for the tablet preview.

But this kinda beats the purpose of defining specific preview screen sizes and checking if the layout adapts properly.

Comment: Did you try it in interactive preview mode

Comment: @Rafsanjani Since Android Studio gets a Render problem, it doesn't show an option to start an interactive preview. Or is there another way to start an interactive preview from AS?

Answer (score 3):

Google just released new [material3-adaptive](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#compose_material3_adaptive_version_10_2) library. It contains [`currentWindowAdaptiveInfo()`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/c9bbb51af4c8814c12172a3f8553dc1e87961b76:compose/material3/material3-adaptive/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/adaptive/AndroidWindowInfo.android.kt;l=47) function that returns `WindowAdaptiveInfo` which has a `WindowSizeClass` and it doesn't depend on activity. You can either use it directly, or at least as an inspiration how to do that.

```
@Preview @Composable fun ScreenPreview() {
    val windowSizeClass = currentWindowAdaptiveInfo().windowSizeClass
}
```

Comment: Ah damit, it is still in Alpha but looks like this is the way to go.

Comment: Weird thing is that even though this is a M3 library, it uses https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/window/core/layout/WindowSizeClass rather than the M3 `WindowSizeClass` library... But it's still in alpha so maybe that'll change.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the answer from @Jan Bína and found out using the library requires API 34.

I'm still using API 33 so I cobbled together a solution based on the library's code and the code from `calculateWindowSizeClass` (in `androidx.compose.material3.windowsizeclass`). It seems to work for my purposes.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi::class)
@Composable
fun currentWindowAdaptiveInfo(): WindowSizeClass {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val size = DpSize(configuration.screenWidthDp.dp, configuration.screenHeightDp.dp)
    return WindowSizeClass.calculateFromSize(size)
}
```